# NGEN for Clickonce with Framework 4.5

Tags: frameworks, .net-4.5, ngen

Referring the link [use-ngen-with-clickonce-deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443955/is-it-possible-to-use-ngen-with-clickonce-deployment) how can i use NGEN for dot net application developed in framework 4.5. I used the code in this link but there is no change in performance. please share the code and help.

Comment: ClickOnce deployment does not permit changes to protected directories like c:\windows\assembly.  Even if you force the user to run a program with admin rights afterwards then ngen is still not guaranteed to provide a noticeable speed increase.  It only improves warm starts for large assemblies.  A notable flaw in that answer is that it completely omits error checking, so easy to miss that you forgot to elevate.  Verifying that Process.ExitCode is 0 is necessary.

Comment: Can anyone explain the benefit of using  Assembly.Load() and if I load all my dlls in application start will it make any sense ? Reference : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/666492/Dynamic-Load-NET-Assembly

Comment: Intentionally delaying the startup of a program is not generally useful.  Although that's another hack whose side-effects rarely make a noticeable difference.  Use a profiler so you can stop guessing at this.

Comment: My application is running in Clickonce and some forms & reports are very slow in first time loading. Then I googled and known about Assembly.Load() method.